# Did not get the content from two dimensional char array

Tags: c

I was tryin to read a text file and return two dimensional char array to main function. 
The text file **ips.txt** as following:

```
hello1
hello2
hello3
```

My code as following:

```
define BUF 20
define TOT 3

char ** getIps(){
    char line[TOT][BUF];
    FILE *plist = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    int total = 0;

    plist = fopen("ips.txt", "r");
    while(fgets(line[i], BUF, plist)) {
        line[i][strlen(line[i]) - 1] = '\0';
        i++;
    }
    return line;

}

int main(void) {
    int i=0;
    char (*line)[TOT];
    line=getIps();
    int total=3;
    for(i = 0; i < total; ++i)
        printf("%s\n", line[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

The main function print out nothing, Not sure where I did wrong?

Comment: 1. check your return value of `fopen`, 2. you can't return the address of a local variable, 3. why is total assigned to 3 in main?

Comment: Your compiler should have warned you that `chat **` is not synonym of `char[3][20]`.  If using GCC/Clang, you could use `-Wall -Wextra`. On other compilers, read the documentation

Answer (score 1):

`getIps` is allocating `line` as a local variable. You can’t return a
local variable that way; that memory is freed as soon as the function
exits.

Also, you’re allocating `line` as a two-dimensional array of `char`, but
the caller is trying to map that onto a one-dimensional array of
pointers to `char`. Again, this doesn’t work.

`getIps` could instead allocate a similar array of pointers, and use
`malloc` to allocate space for each string. However, since the caller
has already started doing that, it’s simpler to just pass the address to `getIps`
and have it use that.

There are other issues. The code assumes there will only be three lines
of input; if there are more, you will overrun the buffer. You’re
hardcoding things that should use `#define`, such as `int total=3`. You
don’t check the return value of `fopen`.

Comment: I should rename the variable line to line2 or other, I already realized it before posting it. I still didn't get your point, can you help me modify one or two code please.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just got understood your answer, Maybe I'm a many years Java guy, I can't switch my brain shortly. btw, I will close this question because I had a similar one. sorry about that and thank you again!